# Computationally efficient way of cross-validating bandwidth for the Nadaraya–Watson estimator

Tags: nonparametric

I'm wondering what short cuts I can take to efficiently estimate a cross-validated bandwidth for the NW estimator.

I have 200,000 observations and running the following code fails to yield after 24 hours:

```
bw <- npregbw(formula = log(outcome) ~ log(iv), data = ss)
fit_nw <- npreg(bw)
```

I modified the code to include `ftol=.01`, `tol=.01`, and still the code does not yield after 12 hours.

I'm wondering if it's sensible to take a random subset of the data and compute the bandwidth on that subset.  Is the bandwidth computed on the subset likely to be similar to the bandwidth on the full dataset?

### What other steps can I take to improve the speed?

To answer the comment below -- I am trying to replicate a procedure described in this paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep06239 in which they say:

> "In order to reduce fluctuations, we first apply a non-parametric
>   fitting method to the data, namely, the Nadaraya-Watson kernel
>   regression. We also compute the 95% (α = 0.05) confidence
>   interval (CI) by the so-called α/2 quantile function over 300 random
>   bootstrapping samples. The power-law exponent is calculated by
>   performing an ordinary least square (OLS) fitting over the results of
>   the Nadaraya-Watson kernel regression in the population interval [104,
>   106] for Brazilian cities, and [105, 107] for American MSAs."

In another one of their papers they describe this process in more detail here: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep04235?origin=ppub#ref46

Where they add:

> where the h is the bandwidth estimated by least squares
>   cross-validation method

I am trying to do something similar for my own purposes (it's not clear to me why NW smoothing was used as oppose to any other kind of smoothing like LOESS, so I'd appreciate some insight into that).  I learned that you can fit the NW kernel regression using `library(np)` via `np::npreg`, and you can perform jackknife cross-validation via `np::npregbw.` . However, given the size of my dataset, this is proving to be untenable

Comment: Can you please give us more information about what you try to achieve, the nature of the data and which packages you use? Subsampling is definitely one option but we might get something even faster. (e.g. through GCV or BO or a simple optimisation algorithm wrapping up the problem.)

Comment: I just added a bit more detail.

Comment: Since there isn't a particularly strong reason for the NW regression (you do it because they did it, they did it because it's non parametric regression) you could try a different non parametric regression that could be more tractable. Splines. Take a look here for a comparison of all these and their implementation in R: https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendices/Appendix-Nonparametric-Regression.pdf

Comment: Excellent, thanks CloseTOC.  Do you have a recommendation on what smoothing spline might be appropriate for this purpose?